# TFS show two columns of work items within a column

Tags: tfs

**Background:**  A person I work for has her TFS set so that her ToDo, Impeded, InProgress, and Done columns show two items wide in each.  The number of tasks has mushroomed recently as management wants to track work at a finer level of granularity.

I'm thinking this is an individual option set (or loaded) on her PC.  I've gone through as many of the configuration options that I have access to.  This might be something that she has special rights to (she is an software development manager and I am just a scrum master)

Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server     Version 16.131.28106.2

**Question:**  The standard view I have had in TFS and Azure DevOps allows for a single item in each column.  What do I change/load/configure/sacrifice in order to get a two wide listing in the columns on my work board?

Thanks for any ideas, help, etc.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems that you want to [Split columns on your Kanban board to show work in progress](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Fboards%2Fsplit-columns%3Fview%3Dazure-devops&data=04%7C01%7Cv-shuqiji%40microsoft.com%7Cc6edb8a0ceee4ee0d98c08d9fd8af7e5%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637819595578332578%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000&sdata=gkM%2BMnzZjzcClf2hwKgcYNFo36fkGCOJGa9cKwHOvx4%3D&reserved=0).

In your Boards >> Setting >> Columns. Enable the **Split column into doing and done** to make the columns show two items wide in each. Please notice that, you can’t split the first and last columns(To Do and Done). Since they are always mapped to the initial and last state.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Bill Bingham is there any updates for this question? Please feel free to let me know whether the answers above can help you and feel free to comment~ Just a remind to [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).